# I am using a Drag an Drop for a custom lock screen. Just want to limit the area of the draggable object

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

I have this lock screen where there are two imageview one is drag and the other is drop. I am making use of the drag and drop. Everything is working great. I just want to limit the drag (imageview) so that it doesn't go beyond the drop(imageView). How can i do it ?

MainActivity.java

```
    package in.ascentinc.demolock;

    import android.content.ClipData;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.DragEvent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        ImageView drag, drop;
        LinearLayout dragLayout,dropLayout;
        float lock_x,lock_y,drop_x,drop_y;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            drag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drag);
            drop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dropTarget);
            dropLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drop_linear_layout);

            drag.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                        lock_x = view.getX();
                        lock_y = view.getY();

                        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

                        Log.d("Sagar","moving");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            dropLayout.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    drop_x = v.getX();
                    drop_y = v.getY();
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: Log.d("Sagar", "drag started");
                            break;
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                            v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape));
                            break;
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                            v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal_shape));
                            if(lock_y > drop_y )
                            {
                                lock_x = drop_x;
                                lock_y = drop_y;
                            }
                            break;
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                            // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                            owner.removeView(view);
                            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                            switch(v.getId()) {

                                case R.id.drop_linear_layout: Log.d("Sagar","dropped");
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: drag.setX(lock_x);
                            drag.setY(lock_y);
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }

    }

activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drag_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drop_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dropTarget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

normal_shape.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >

</shape>

shape.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >


    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFF0000" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA"
        android:startColor="#DD000000" />


</shape>
```